# How to update timer values in text label of push button in qt designer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am new in pyqt and want to know how to update timer values in text label of push button , which is inside the window.I just want, when I will run my script it will open the new window containing the button and in that button text our timer will show us the timers value and we are taking the timer value as input.
My code is shown below:-

```
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

timeData=0

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQT tuts!")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('pythonlogo.png'))
        #while 1:
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        btn.setText(self.timer())
        btn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        btn.resize(100,100)
        btn.move(100,100)
        self.show()

    #def updateTimer(self):

    def timer(self):
      uin = input("enter the time : ")
      when_to_stop = abs(int(uin))
      while when_to_stop > -1:
     m, s = divmod(when_to_stop, 60)
     h, m = divmod(m, 60)
     time_left = str(h).zfill(2) + ":" + str(m).zfill(2) + ":" + str(s).zfill(2)

     print(time_left+'\r')
     time.sleep(1)
     when_to_stop -= 1
         global timeData
         timeData=timeData+2
         time.sleep(0.9)    
         return(str(time_left+'\r'))

def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Please help me to sought out my problem

Comment: Recommendation: never use input() in a GUI, why use a horrible terminal if you have the beautiful GUI?

Comment: @eyllanesc ok sir but how i will be able to update the timer values please help me

Comment: Why do not you use a QLineEdit or a QSpinBox?